# Casual versus formal jacket

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Ciao tutti, is there a word that means “formal jacket”, as in the expression "jacket and tie" or "suit jacket”? Or is “giacca” used for all sorts of jackets, from winter clothing to formal clothing?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Answer (score 5):

[Giacca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/giacca/) (as reported by Treccani dictionary) is a generic term to indicate a male or female garment, generally made of cloth, but also leather, wool, and similar, covering the upper part of the body till below the waist, provided with sleeves.

> **giacca** s. f. [dal fr. jaque «giaco»].Indumento per uomo o per donna, generalmente di stoffa, ma anche di
>   pelle, di lana a maglia, e sim., che ricopre la parte superiore del
>   corpo fin sotto la vita, ed è fornito di maniche

*Giacca e cravatta* (jacket and tie) indicates a formal jacket, but sometimes, referring to the type of jacket we use *giacca doppiopetto* or just *doppiopetto* to indicate a formal and elegant male jacket.

In everyday speech the term for winter clothing would be *giacca a vento* or *giaccone*.

Other variants of giacca like giacchino, [giacchetto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/giacchetto1/) indicate a smaller and tight female jacket.

> giacchétto s. m. [da giacchetta]. – Giacca più piccola e attillata di
>   quella comune, di stoffa o in maglia di lana; in partic., la giacca da
>   donna

Answer (score 2):

In Italy, the equivalent expression of "jacket and tie" or "suit jacket," is generally used for an invitation to a party.

You can use these formulas:

> - **“È gradito l’abito scuro”**: gentlemen must wear a formal suit, ladies an elegant dress.
> - **“Dress Code: Black Tie“** (yes, in English) or **“Cravatta nera”**, that means that gentlemen must wear smoking, ladies an evening gown.
> - **“Dress Code: White Tie“**,  or “**Cravatta Bianca”**, that means that gentlemen must wear frac, ladies a long evening gown.

Giacca, as Abarisone said, is used for all sort of jackets and outerwears used to cover the half upper side of the body.

Comment: Can you provide any references as the use of such terms to indicate formal clothing?

Comment: @Bakuriu sure! These are the etiquette rules. In Italy, we follow the “Galateo” rules. You can find a copy published by The University of Chicago Press: “Galateo: Or, The Rules of Polite Behavior” and you can find the specific "dress code" rules also here: https://alleyoop.ilsole24ore.com/2016/06/21/inviti-e-dress-codes-sai-essere-adeguata-alloccasione/?refresh_ce=1

Comment: @Bakuriu in case you were interested in learning more about "Galateo" you can find an interesting article here: http://tuscantraveler.com/2014/florence/italian-life-rules-galateo-della-casa-guide-to-polite-manners/

Comment: The original Galateo by Della Casa wasn't exactly about ties and the like...

Comment: @DaG obviously wasn’t, Monsignor Giovanni Della Casa wrote it around the year 1550, but now we have a modern version.

Answer (score 1):

**giacca da abito** seems fairly common from a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22giacca%20da%20abito%22) and I think it's fairly clear.